# What are semi-files?

Tags: linux, files

I'm reading a paper about Android/Linux. It contains a line I'm not able to understand. I tried searching about "semi-files" but nothing relative came up. Can someone please rephrase it or explain it in more detail?

> Linux provides many system functionalities as semi-files.

Source of paper: [Google Android: A State-of-the-Art Review of Security Mechanisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5101v1)
The sentence is at page 7/42, line 6.

Comment: I don't remember seeing that expression before, it's definitely not standard terminology. The paper is not written in very good English, this may be a bad translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referring to the fact that Linux (like all Unix-style systems) exposes most of the resources it manages through objects which look like files: `/dev`-style devices, `/proc` and `/sys` entries... In the context of your quote, this property is mentioned because it allows access permissions to be reasoned about in a consistent fashion.